# I am having troubles fully understanding how Context works in ANdroid Studio(Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having difficulties understanding Context in Android Studio after reading through docs and answers from Stackoverflow. From what I understand Context gives the Context of the current application/object. (The lines which I need help with are denoted by *****)

When using `val context = holder.view.context` am I getting the Context from my respective XML views?

If that is the case why is it necessary to input that context into the intent object `val intent = Intent(context, DetailActivity::class.java)`?

Can't I just use `this` instead? I would appreciate if anybody could walk me through on how Context work with examples thanks!

```
class LetterAdapter :
RecyclerView.Adapter<LetterAdapter.LetterViewHolder>() {

// Generates a [CharRange] from 'A' to 'Z' and converts it to a list
private val list = ('A').rangeTo('Z').toList()

/**
 * Provides a reference for the views needed to display items in your list.
 */
class LetterViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val button = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_item)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}

/**
 * Creates new views with R.layout.item_view as its template
 */
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LetterViewHolder {
    val layout = LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false)
    // Setup custom accessibility delegate to set the text read
    layout.accessibilityDelegate = Accessibility
    return LetterViewHolder(layout)
}

/**
 * Replaces the content of an existing view with new data
 */
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LetterViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = list.get(position)
    holder.button.text = item.toString()
    holder.button.setOnClickListener {
        val context = holder.view.context *****

        val intent = Intent(context, DetailActivity::class.java)*****

        intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.LETTER, holder.button.text.toString())



        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `this` instead of context in an adapter. Because adapter classes do not have context, but Activity classes do (since they extend `AppCompatActivity` or `Activity` classes that extends Context at some level of their hierarchy). So you can use `this` in Activity classes but not in Adapter classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When using val context = holder.view.context am I getting the Context
> from my respective XML views?

here context would be the Activity, you can get the Activity context from the views of the Activity

> If that is the case why is it necessary to input that context into the
> intent object val intent = Intent(context,
> DetailActivity::class.java)?

The Intent object expects the first parameter of type Context in this case. See [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#pubctors) for more information

> Can't I just use this instead?

No. Because RecyclerView.Adapter is not a Context or subclass of Context